# MomentJs custom .fromNow()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to customize the `moment([2018,1,1]).fromNow()` behaviour.

The requirements are:

- If interval is <= 60 days, use “days”.
- If interval is > 60 days and <= 2 years away, use “months”
- If interval is > 2 years, use “years”
- My days/months/years should be localized

One work around that I thought of was :

```
getCountDown(){
  const targetDate = Moment(myFutureDate);
  const diffInDays = Math.abs(Moment().diff(targetDate, 'days'));
  if(diffInDays <= 60) return diffInDays;

  const diffInMonths = Math.abs(Moment().diff(targetDate, 'months'));
  const diffInYears = Math.abs(Moment().diff(targetDate, 'years',true));

  if(diffInDays > 60 && diffInYears <= 2) return diffInMonths;

  return diffInYears;
}
```

Obviously I only get the integer values for this, and I don't have the localized strings for days/months/years. I can add them myself, but as a programmer this feels too hacky and verbose.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can do this more efficiently with MomentJs? At first I was looking at `.fromNow()`, but I couldn't find any customization possibilities in the documentation. (Or did I fail to see how I could compose some functions to achieve my goal)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the second half of https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/ seems to allow a function for eg. relativetime.past

Comment: @Shameen , I'll have a look at that part and get back to you. Thanks for the tip.